# How to update one specific required property without touching other required properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

## Problem

I am attempting to update one property `productPrice` without having to update all the other required properties. I would like to pass in any single property to change individually, so this problem is not only for updating `propertyPrice` but also the other properties (like `propertyTitle` etc.). When I attempt to update the value of `productPrice`, I get an error:

#### Error Output

```
{
    "errors": {
        "productDescription": {
            "properties": {
                "message": "Product Description is required",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "productDescription"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "productDescription"
        },
        "productTitle": {
            "properties": {
                "message": "Product Title is required",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "productTitle"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "productTitle"
        },
        "productPrice": {
            "properties": {
                "message": "Product Price is required",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "productPrice"
            },
"_message": "Products validation failed"
}
```

## Relevant code

#### Mongoose Model

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
productPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Product Price is required']
    },
    productTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Product Title is required'],
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 30
    },
    productDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Product Description is required'],
        minlength: 40,
        maxlength: 1000
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Products", ProductSchema);
```

#### Controller

```
// UPDATE one by ID
exports.updateProduct = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const updateOps = {};
  for (const ops of req.body) {
    updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
  }
  Product.findOneAndReplace(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: updateOps },
    (err, event) => {
      if (err) {
        err.reason = "Update failed"
        res.status(404).send(err);
      }
      res.status(200).json(event);
    }
  );
};
```

#### App.js

```
app
  .route("/products/:_id")
  .put(productController.updateProduct)
```

#### Postman Request

- PUT request to */products/:_id*
- Raw JSON input

```
[
    {"propName": "productPrice", "value": 123}
]
```

## Research

Not sure if this solution is the only; although, I stumbled upon it and have not tried it out yet: [GitHub, Automattic/mongoose Issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5285). I'd like to ultimately know if there are other solutions to resolve this error.

#### Background

I am very new to programming / Node, because of that, I would greatly appreciate a relatively more descriptive answer if possible.

**Thank you!**

## Updates

Thanks to @user9879287 for pointing out incorrect output of `updateOps`. This update should solve that, outputting `{productPrice: 123}`:

```
    // UPDATE one by ID
    exports.updateProduct = (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const updateOps = {};
      for (const ops of req.body) {
        const propChange = ops.propName;
        const propValue = ops.value;
        updateOps[propChange] = propValue;
        console.log(updateOps)
      }
      Product.findOneAndReplace(
        { _id: id },
        { $set: updateOps },
        (err, event) => {
          if (err) {
            err.reason = "Update failed"
            res.status(404).send(err);
          }
          res.status(200).json(event);
        }
      );
    };
```

Comment: what is in updateOps if you console.log it?

Comment: You are right, I am going to update the controller so the output of `updateOps` now outputs `{productPrice: 123}`. I am still receiving the same error, and `productPrice` is still not registering along with the required errors for the unchanged properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `updateOps` has this format like:
`{productPrice:123}`
then you can do code below as your current one:

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: updateOps },
    {new: true},
    (err, event) => {
      if (err) {
        err.reason = "Update failed"
        res.status(404).send(err);
      }
      res.send(event);
    }
  );
```

or you can just pass the actual value e.g. `123` with your request, then you can do:

```
let value = 123 // just to mock that you get the value from the request
Product.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id },
    { $set:{productPrice:value} },
    (err, event) => {
      if (err) {
        err.reason = "Update failed"
        res.status(404).send(err);
      }
      res.status(200).json(event);
    }
  );
```

Hope that makes sense to you

Comment: I updated my Controller to output based on your answer (`{productPrice: 123}`). Unfortunately, I am still getting the exact same error output. Thank you

Comment: @newdev, sorry ive changed the query to `findOneAndUpdate` instead of `findOneAndReplace` as you are only updating one field, not the entire document

Comment: I still had the `findOneAndReplace` in my code. I just tried it with `findOneAndUpdate` and all I got was `null` return and the change did not take.

Comment: Just did a few checks with different--valid--MongoDB `:_id`'s and I am still getting `null` return, status  = 200 while the value stays the same in the database.

Comment: thats odd, can you try a test query like findById(id), see if it finds some docs

Comment: Hit my--GET all--endpoint, then used those `:_id`'s to hit my `findById()` endpoint; I am returning specific docs.

Comment: sorry, i did not quite get what you mean

Comment: apologies, I need to sharpen my vocab. What was I vague on, my test (in the comment above yours), or the question in general?

Comment: so when you try  findById(id), are you getting results?

Comment: Yes, I am getting results when I try findById(id)

Comment: I've updated my answer, ive added `{new: true}` in the first code block and just do `res.send(event)`